# I want to scrap one data from a URL page. I'm using Excel VBA

Tags: excel

1)**I want to scrap the phone number** which appears in this URL: https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/96599356/
The phone is 607176984.
Up to now I have been able to get the other data that I need, from that URL .

2)**Using Chrome, I get this code** of the URL (the lines that are related to this case)

```
<div class="ide-box-contact module-contact-gray contact-data-container ">
<h2 class="txt-big txt-bold mb-small">
Anunciante
</h2>
<div id="contact-phones-container" class="hidden-contact-phones no-form">
<a role="button" aria-label="contact phone" class="icon-phone hidden-contact-phones_link" href="">
<span class="hidden-contact-phones_text">Ver teléfono</span>
<span class="animation_circle">
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="professional-name">
<div class="name">
Particular
</div>
<span class="particular">
<span class="icon-block"></span>
```

**3)I have written this code in Excel VBA**

```
EnSub detalles_de_cada_trastero()
ActiveSheet.Select

hoja_actual = ActiveSheet.Name
   
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlim As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlims As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim url As String
    
url = "https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/96599356/"
```

XMLPage.Open "Get", url_corregida, False
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
On Error Resume Next
XMLPage.send
htmldoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

```
        
# First: I try with this code. It doesn't work
        
       Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("hidden-contact-phones_text")

        For Each htmlim In htmlims
            Sheets("hoja_actual").Cells(Fila, 12).Value = htmlim.innerText        
        texto = htmlim.innerText   ' what I get is  "Ver teléfono"        
        Next htmlim
====================================================
   
#  'Second: I try with this code
        Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("icon-phone hidden-contact-phones_formatted-phone _mobilePhone")

        For Each htmlim In htmlims '*************************The control doesn't enter in this For-Next.   It jumps it              
        texto = htmlim.getAttribute("href")        
        'Sheets("hoja_actual").Cells(Fila, 12).Value = htmlim.innerText        
        Next htmlim
        
        '===============================================================
# 'third: I try this
        
        texto = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("icon-phone hidden-contact-phones_formatted-phone _mobilePhone")  'Gives "nothing"
        
        texto = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("icon-phone hidden-contact-phones_formatted-phone _mobilePhone").Item
        texto = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("icon-phone hidden-contact-phones_formatted-phone _mobilePhone").toString 
  
        
        '===============================================================
#       'Fourth: I try this
        
        texto = htmldoc.getElementById("contact-phones-container")
 
        Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementById("contact-phones-container")    'Error!
      
        For Each htmlim In htmlims            
           texto_1 = htmlim.Children(0).innerText  'sale profesonal'
            texto = htmlim.getAttribute("href")  
            texto_2 = htmlim.Children(1).innerText         
        Next



Any help will be wellcome
```

Comment: Use find / replace and replace that number with 0 or ""

Answer (score 1):

My experience is terrible with this method.. Imaging 300 products with price and availability it did about 2.5 hours. As I was suggested few years ago..the most robust way to do it is through python.

But here is an example

```
Sub ExtractPhoneNumber()
Dim url As String
Dim html As Object
Dim phoneElement As Object
Dim phoneNumber As String

' Get the HTML content of the page
url = "https://example.com"
Set html = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
html.Open "GET", url, False
html.send

' Parse the HTML to find the phone number
Set phoneElement = html.responseXML.querySelector(".icon-phone")
If Not phoneElement Is Nothing Then
    phoneNumber = phoneElement.getAttribute("href")
    ' Extract the phone number from the href attribute
    phoneNumber = Mid(phoneNumber, InStr(phoneNumber, "tel:") + 4)
End If

' Print the phone number to the immediate window
Debug.Print phoneNumber
```

End Sub